# Users Page During a Beta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Is the Users page supposed to work during a beta?  I navigated there directly and the reputation counts seem way off.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the *weekly* reputation totals. Look to the upper-right of the user listing. Try switching to the 'all' tab and you will see the *total* reputation earnings.

Sorry about the confusion. I've been caught by that one myself.